# database INNER JOIN

Tags: c#, mysql, database

These are the two set up tables

**LOGIN TABLE**
[image]

**USER'S NAME**
[image]

I want to create something like the User will key in their `USER_ID` and `USER_PWD` in a textbox. IF the user successfully login, it will say " HI + PATNAME ".

I have created this code so far but it isnt working.

```
string sqlStr = "Select patpro.'PATNAME' FROM patpro,useform where USER_ID=@name and USER_PWD=@password and useform.'USER_ID' = patpro.'USERID'";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtValue.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Password);
cmd.CommandText = sqlStr;
cmd.Connection = connection;

connection.Open();
MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (login.HasRows)
{
login.Read();
string name = (login["USER_ID"].ToString());
txtAssignID1.Text = "Login verified. Hi, " + name + "\n";
}
```

Comment: How it is not working? Try removing single quotes from field names and use `while (login.Read())` block to assign value into textbox (also use `INNER JOIN` with `ON useform.USER_ID = patpro.USERID` if both tables have same column ID).

Comment: what kind of "not working"? An error, unexpected behaviour, or what? What debugging have you done? Have you checked that your variable values are what you expected? Have you run a sample version of the query in Workbench to check the logic? It's a simple enough query but you should still make basic checks on it. If you've already done all that, you should mention it in the question then we know where you're up to.

Comment: it catch an error

Comment: What kind of error/exception? Please explain the error in detail. I suspected you're executing wrong SQL statement or use wrong construction when reading results.

Comment: must we guess the error?? Give us a clue. We're not mind-readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you're trying to use `login["USER_ID"].ToString()` which `USER_ID` is a nonexistent column definition inside current `SELECT` statement. Hence, you should add column names which defined in `SELECT` results like `login["PATNAME"]` and use proper `INNER JOIN` statement instead:

```
string sqlStr = @"SELECT patpro.PATNAME FROM patpro INNER JOIN useform 
                  ON useform.USER_ID = patpro.USERID 
                  WHERE useform.USER_ID = @name AND useform.USER_PWD = @password";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtValue.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Password);
cmd.CommandText = sqlStr;
cmd.Connection = connection;

connection.Open();
MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (login.HasRows)
{
    // read value inside the loop, because MySqlDataReader is forward-only
    while (login.Read())
    {
        string name = login["PATNAME"].ToString();
        txtAssignID1.Text = "Login verified. Hi, " + name + "\n";
    }
}
```

**Additional note:**  Better to use `using` statement for `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlDataReader` to ensure immediate disposal of MySQL connection objects after fetching query results.